# how to use Router.navigate() with named router outlet and url parameter

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have troubles using named router outlet, I think I am using it wrong although I assume I followed the angular docs:

router configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [

    {path: 'checktypes', component: ChecktypeComponent},
    {path: 'checktypes/:id', component: ChecktypeDetailsComponent, outlet: 'checktypeDetails'},

  ];
```

template of `ChecktypeComponent`:

```
...
<router-outlet name="checktypeDetails"></router-outlet>
...
```

In the `ChecktypeComponent` (on route `/checktypes`):

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {checktypeDetails: ['checktypes', 1]}}]);
```

I hardcoded the id 1 just for the sake of simplicity. I always get the error `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'checktypes/1'`. I tried a lot of stuff but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use as following

For route like

```
{
 path: 'update-book/:book-id',
 component: BookUpdateComponent,
 outlet: 'bookPopup' 
}
```

You can navigate as

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { bookPopup: [ 'update-book', book.id ] }}]);
```

The resulting URL will have the following structure:

```
http://localhost:4200/book(bookList:book-detail//bookPopup:add-book)
```

Comment: Refer https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-named-router-outlet-popup-example