# How to specify router outlet In angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to specify the router outlet while programatic routing in angular?

```
 this.router.navigate(['products/item'])
```

Like this:

```
 this.router.navigate(['products/item'], {outlet: 'items-outlet'})
```

Cause I've some named outlets.

Without any name outlet my routing is working fine.

But when I add name to my outlets, then it spits out cannot find routes matching 'products/items'.

Adding router outlet name is mandatory.

It will be a great help if I can specify the outlet like this: (or any other workaround)

Like this:

```
 this.router.navigate(['products/item'], {outlet: 'items-outlet'})
```

Comment: ```this.router.navigate(['./', {outlets: {nameOutlet: ['test']}}]);```

Comment: have tried this???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use Router.navigate() with named router outlet and url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583274/how-to-use-router-navigate-with-named-router-outlet-and-url-parameter)